# Aggregation pipeline with $group and $limit on N-previous results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, limit

I want to run a query that only $groups the most recent N-results (10 for example) by date. This is meant to be a rolling-sample, where every time the query happens, it samples a few of the last answers.

This is how I *think* the pipeline should work:

```
    Answer.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                user_team_oid: team_oid
            },
        },
        {
            $sort: { 
                create_date: 1 
            }
        },
        {
            $limit: 10
        },
        {
            $group: {
                "user_team_oid":    "$team_oid",
                "avg_a":            { $avg: "$var_a" },
                "avg_b":            { $avg: "$var_b" },
                "avg_c":            { $avg: "$var_c" },
                "avg_d":            { $avg: "$var_d" },
                "avg_e":            { $avg: "$var_e" },
            }
        }
    ])
```

However, the result continues to be "undefined".

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you get any results if you remove the grouping stage?

Comment: show us some docs and expected output?

Comment: @Taplar - when I removed the grouping stage, it produced the last 10 results, as expected.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/  `$group` needs to have an `_id` so it knows how to perform the grouping.

Comment: @Taplar - You're right. I needed only to change "user_team_oid" to "_id", and it worked perfectly. If you post an answer I will accept. Thank you.

Comment: Since all I did was provide a link, I would encourage you to self answer your question and provide the solution you came up with.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

The `$group` stage requires a `"_id"` key. In this case, mis-naming the `"_id"` as `"user_team_oid"` was the issue. *(See working code below)*

The good news is that this pattern works quite well, and allows sorting and filtering prior to `$group` stage.

The bad news is that the issue should have been resolved with a re-visit to the [MongoDB Aggregation documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) (Thanks @Taplar for the friendly reminder)

**Working Code:**

```
Answer.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            user_team_oid: team_oid
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: { 
            create_date: 1 
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id":              "$team_oid",
            "avg_a":            { $avg: "$var_a" },
            "avg_b":            { $avg: "$var_b" },
            "avg_c":            { $avg: "$var_c" },
            "avg_d":            { $avg: "$var_d" },
            "avg_e":            { $avg: "$var_e" },
        }
    }
])
```